# 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\bin\java.exe" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=49508:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.3\bin" -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\USER\Desktop\spring boot my study\customer\target\classes;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.7.13\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.7.13.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.7.13\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.7.13.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.3.28\spring-aop-5.3.28.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.7\aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.7.13\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.7.13.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\4.0.3\HikariCP-4.0.3.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.3.28\spring-jdbc-5.3.28.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\1.3.3\jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\2.2.3\jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.6.15.Final\hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.4.3.Final\jboss-logging-3.4.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.12.23\byte-buddy-1.12.23.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.4.2.Final\jandex-2.4.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.1.2.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.8\jaxb-runtime-2.3.8.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\2.3.8\txw2-2.3.8.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.12\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.12.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\com\sun\activation\jakarta.activation\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.7.13\spring-data-jpa-2.7.13.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.7.13\spring-data-commons-2.7.13.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.3.28\spring-orm-5.3.28.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.3.28\spring-context-5.3.28.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.3.28\spring-tx-5.3.28.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.3.28\spring-beans-5.3.28.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.36\slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.3.28\spring-aspects-5.3.28.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.7.13\spring-boot-starter-web-2.7.13.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.7.13\spring-boot-starter-2.7.13.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.7.13\spring-boot-2.7.13.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.7.13\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.13.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.7.13\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.7.13.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.12\logback-classic-1.2.12.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.12\logback-core-1.2.12.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.17.2\log4j-to-slf4j-2.17.2.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.17.2\log4j-api-2.17.2.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.36\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.36.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.30\snakeyaml-1.30.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.7.13\spring-boot-starter-json-2.7.13.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.13.5\jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.13.5\jackson-annotations-2.13.5.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.13.5\jackson-core-2.13.5.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.13.5\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.13.5.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.13.5\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.13.5.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.13.5\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.13.5.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.3.28\spring-web-5.3.28.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.3.28\spring-webmvc-5.3.28.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.3.28\spring-expression-5.3.28.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\com\mysql\mysql-connector-j\8.0.33\mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.28\lombok-1.18.28.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.7.13\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.7.13.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.76\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.76\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.76.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.76\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.76.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\2.3.3\jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.3.28\spring-core-5.3.28.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.3.28\spring-jcl-5.3.28.jar;C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\com\vladmihalcea\hibernate-types-5\2.16.2\hibernate-types-5-2.16.2.jar" customer.example.customer.CustomerApplication

.   ____          _            __ _ _
/\ / ***'* __ _ *(*)* __  __ _ \ \ \ 

( ( )_*_ | '_ | '*| | '* / *` | \ \ \ 

\/  __*)| |*)| | | | | || (*| |  ) ) ) )
'  |****| .__|*| |*|*| |*_*, | / / / /
=========|*|==============|***/=/*/*/*/
:: Spring Boot ::               (v2.7.13)

2023-07-20 20:36:04.608  INFO 17756 --- [           main] c.example.customer.CustomerApplication   : Starting CustomerApplication using Java 1.8.0_321 on DESKTOP-PHLKGHM with PID 17756 (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\spring boot my study\customer\target\classes started by USER in C:\Users\USER\Desktop\spring boot my study\customer)
2023-07-20 20:36:04.616  INFO 17756 --- [           main] c.example.customer.CustomerApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-07-20 20:36:05.611  INFO 17756 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-07-20 20:36:05.624  INFO 17756 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 6 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-07-20 20:36:06.121  INFO 17756 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-07-20 20:36:06.143  INFO 17756 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-07-20 20:36:06.143  INFO 17756 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.76]
2023-07-20 20:36:06.321  INFO 17756 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-07-20 20:36:06.321  INFO 17756 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1612 ms
2023-07-20 20:36:06.507  INFO 17756 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-07-20 20:36:06.560  INFO 17756 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.15.Final
2023-07-20 20:36:06.692  INFO 17756 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2023-07-20 20:36:06.839  INFO 17756 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-07-20 20:36:07.409  INFO 17756 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-07-20 20:36:07.424  INFO 17756 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2023-07-20 20:36:07.446  INFO 17756 --- [           main] Hibernate Types                          : This framework is proudly powered by:

> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > 

---

| |  | |                         (*)   | |
| |__| |*   _ _ __   ___ _ __ ___ _ ***| |* ___ _ __   ___ ___
|  __  | | | | '* \ / _ \ '__/ __| / __| **/ _ \ '* \ / __/ _ 

| |  | | |*| | |*) |  **/ |  _* \ _* \ ||  **/ | | | (*|  __/
|*|  |*|_*, | .**/ _**|*|  |***/*|***/___**|*| |*|_**_**|
**/ | |
|***/|*|

At Hypersistence, we only build amazing tools, like Hibernate Types, Flexy Pool, or Hypersistence Optimizer.

What if there were a tool that could automatically detect JPA and Hibernate performance issues?

Hypersistence Optimizer is that tool! For more details, go to:

https://vladmihalcea.com/hypersistence-optimizer/
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

Hibernate: drop table if exists customer
2023-07-20 20:36:08.048 ERROR 17756 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111
2023-07-20 20:36:08.048  WARN 17756 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111
2023-07-20 20:36:08.048  INFO 17756 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-07-20 20:36:08.064  INFO 17756 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2023-07-20 20:36:08.064  INFO 17756 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-07-20 20:36:08.079  INFO 17756 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-07-20 20:36:08.110 ERROR 17756 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1156) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:910) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) [spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) [spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) [spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) [spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at customer.example.customer.CustomerApplication.main(CustomerApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111
at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getTypeName(Dialect.java:404) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.mapping.Column.getSqlType(Column.java:238) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.StandardTableExporter.getSqlCreateStrings(StandardTableExporter.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.StandardTableExporter.getSqlCreateStrings(StandardTableExporter.java:31) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:326) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:169) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:168) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
... 20 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 1

i need to fix this problem

Comment: Edit your question and remove everything that isn't useful. Such as big ascii-art arrows.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

hey I find the issue I used type def to store many phone numbers with json format and inside I only use type like below

```
@Type(type = "json")
@Column(name = "mobile")
```

after I mention the inside @Column I add columndefinition=json after adding that my problem fix

```
@Type(type = "json")
@Column(name = "mobile",columnDefinition = "json")
```